# Aesthetically correct code for storing/displaying basic shapes

Tags: c++, architecture, opengl-es

I'm using ES 3.0 (basically GL 3.3 without geometry shaders) to be able to port my programs to almost everything

My helpful framework/wrapper written on C++. Basically its everything what can be found inside of [quick reference card](https://www.khronos.org/files/opengles3-quick-reference-card.pdf): Buffer/Shader/ShaderProgram/Framebuffer/Texture/etc. (pretty basic stuff, I do believe everyone have classes like that)

I noticed that when I need to draw a basic shapes such as full-screen quad, triangles, spheres I always doing it in-place, its not a part of my framework. And I kinda hate it, because I'm repeating myself again and again. It is really unpleasant thing to do

How aesthetically and technically right I can add such a functionality to my framework?

(in advance: for platforms like android context loss is possible, so pause/restore mechanism required)

Comment: I don't think we can answer this question, since all I can tell you that **yes** it is possible, but I can't give you any advice on how to do it without knowing how your tools work.

Answer (score 0):

SFML has similar functionality. Here's its structural frame:

```
class Drawable {
  friend class RenderTarget;
 protected: // hidden from everyone but subclasses and RenderTarget
  virtual void draw(RenderTarget&) const = 0;
};

class RenderTarget {
 public:
  void draw(Drawable& drawable) {
    drawable.draw(*this);
  } 
};

class RectangleShape : public Drawable {
 protected:
  void draw(RenderTarget&) const override {
    // the algorithm
  }
};

void use() {
  RectangleShape shape;
  RenderTarget& target = get();
  target.draw(shape);
}
```

(Actually it's more complicated: I omitted virtual destructors, unnecessary inheritance levels etc.)

Comment: as I can see, SFML tries to hide OpenGL commands in RenderTarget (which is some sort of context?)

I'm not sure if I need such a high-level abstractions, I would love to keep everything in a bit lower level

Comment: Yes, SFML is an OpenGL facade. Unfortunately, I don't know if the idea in my answer can be effectively transferred to a lower level.